# Need help to understand an example of recursion

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I was trying to understand an example written in JavaScript. Actually, I'm reading the book *Eloquent JavaScript*, but got stuck while reading a topic about recursion.

Here is the statement of the example:

> By starting from the number 1 and repeatedly either adding 5 or
>   multiplying by 3, an infinite set of numbers can be produced. How
>   would you write a function that, given a number, tries to find a
>   sequence of such additions and multiplications that produces that
>   number?

Here is the code of the example:

```
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(current, history) {
    if (current == target) {
      return history;
    } else if (current > target) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) || 
             find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
    }
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What specifically don't you understand? Have you stepped through it in the debugger or put in logging statements to get an idea of what's happening? Or "played computer" with a pen and paper to step through the code?

Comment: Yes, actually I just tried to understand that how this code is working on a paper manually.

Comment: Actually, I can't understand the working of logical OR "||" gate used in the return statement...

Comment: The `||` operator in Javascript works on values which don't have to be booleans; in this case `find` returns either a string named `history` which contains a mathematical expression (so it is not empty), or it returns `null`. The `||` operator will give the result of the first recursive call if it's a non-empty string, otherwise it does the second recursive call and returns that result; so if either of the two attempts succeeds in finding an expression (as a string), it returns that string, otherwise it returns null.

Comment: "I'm reading the book Eloquent JavaScript" - seriously, from all the questions about this book's examples, it must be absurdly bad. I lost count how often i read that in a question so far.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Or it must be very popular, so that there are many people reading it and asking questions. Nobody is asking questions on SO about explanations I've written, but that's probably because I have not written anything popular rather than an indication of good quality. On the other hand, the fact that people who read a textbook still have questions to clarify their understanding is not an indictment of the book; anyone learning a difficult topic will need to ask questions about what they have read sometimes.

Comment: I know, the comment is not completely serious. However, what remains, is that when reading a textbook, and getting completely stuck, alarm bells should be ringing. Chances are, the book is aimed at a different audience, or is not a good match for the person reading it.

Comment: This is the best introductory book I've found.  I've recommended it highly, and do believe it is one of the most-read books on the subject now.  So I would expect more questions about it.  I've seen quite a few on this particular example, which I'm hoping the authors sees as a target for improvement in a later edition.  But the number of basic "I don't understand recursion" questions shows that the general topic is difficult for many to comprehend.

Comment: "I'm hoping the authors sees as a target for improvement" that would be a productive result :) another result is, that i obtained the info, that it is indeed a popular book, and have at least one voice saying it's good.

Comment: IMO pencil and paper are one of the best ways to grok recursion: it forces you to step through the code in your head. If there's a small *chunk* of code you don't understand, like the use of `||` here, it's easy enough to test in the REPL by using the potential return values of `find` (which would be `history`, `null`, or the results of the `||`, which is one of two `find` results. Putting in some `console.log`, potentially with an additional parameter (indentation level) can also help understand recursion pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function calls itself until the branch meets a condition where it doesn't call itself.

In this case the chain stops when the current value equals or is higher than the initial target value.

But I think that it should return null when the current equals the target.

With some extra logging one can follow better what happens.

In the snippet below, it exits with null when it meets the target of 11.
And because the result is null, it multiplies by 3 to get the final solution.

```js
function findSolution(target) {

  function find(current, step, action) {
    console.log('step: '+step, '\taction: '+action, '\tcurrent: '+current);
    step++;
    if (current == target) {
       console.log(current+'='+target+' so exit with null')
       return null;
    } else if (current > target) {
       return current;
    } else {
      return find(current + 5, step, '+ 5') || find(current * 3, step, '* 3');
    }
  }

  return find(1, 0, 'start');
}

console.log(findSolution(11));
```